# Anti-derivation of an exterior algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, exterior-algebra, universal-property

Let $K$ be a commutative ring. $M$ is a free $K$-module of rank $m$. $E(M)$ is the exterior algebra defined by $M$. 
$\iota$ is a $K$-homomorphism from $M$ to $E(M)$ such that $\iota(x)=-x$. Since $\iota(x)^2=0$, $\iota$ can be extended to a unique algebra homomorphism from $E(M)$ to itself. We will use $\iota$ to denote this algebra homomorphism, and denote $\bar{a}=\iota(a)$, $a\in E(M)$.

The next part is from N.Jacobson's Basic Algebra(2nd).

[image]
[image]

---

I can read and understand the proof of the lemma till the last sentence above. 

My question is why the image of the algebra homomorphism $f$ above has that matrix form. And actually I think I can understand the elements in position (1,1) and (2,2) of the matrix. But why the (2,1) position will be $D(a)$. And I am also confused with that $D$ becomes a $K$-endomorphism after that. 

I don't know if there requires any knowledge about universal property or something like that. Actually I have learnt some about that. But I just can't figure it out.

---

**Editted:**I understand that $f$ in the original definition is a $K$-homomorphism and satisfies $f(x)^2=0$, $x\in M$. So by the universal property of $E(M)$, $f$ can be uniquely extended to an algebra homomorphism. Let's say $f'$. And $f'$ is from $E(M)$ to $M_2(E(M))$. But even though $f'$ is an algebra homomorphism, it seems that we can't get 
$$f'(a)=\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ D(a) & \bar{a} \end{pmatrix},  a\in E(M).$$
Now the form of $f'$ can just show it is a $K$-homomorphism. At the same time, by calculation, $$f'(ab)=f'(a)f'(b)=\begin{pmatrix} ab & 0 \\ D(a)b+\bar{a}D(b) & \bar{ab} \end{pmatrix}, a,b\in E(M).$$The (2,1) position is not the expected form $D(ab)$! So again, I turn back to my origin question, why the (2,1) position of the image of $f'$ is of that form. How can one determine the value of that position? 

Thank you once more for reading this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your feeling is exactly right: it is invoking the universal property of $E(M)$.

The property is: any $K$ homomorphism from $M$ into an associative $K$ algebra $A$ such that $f(x)^2=0$ can be extended uniquely to a $K$ algebra homomorphism from all of $E(M)$ into $A$.

All of $x\mapsto x$, $x\mapsto -x$ and $x\mapsto Dx$ are extendable linear maps from $M$ into $E(M)$. They are also entries of $f$. In effect, the extension of $f$ is the matrix of extensions of its entries. The reason we can recognize the matrix is of that form is because these extensions are unique. (For clarity: the uniqueness is given by the universal property of $E(M)$, and we are not talking about the uniqueness that the lemma is striving to prove.)

It looks like Jacobson abused $D$ a little by letting it denote its extension as well as itself.

Comment: @Andylang Ah, to be clear, the Lemma is proving uniqueness of *the resulting anti-derivation*, and the uniqueness I was referring to is that of the extension produced by the universal property.

Comment: @rschwieb :Since this $f$ makes the diagram of the universal property commute,  then we can claim this $f$ is the right $\bar{f}$ we are looking for by that $\bar{f}$ is unique. Is that right?

Comment: @Andylang That doesn't necessarily establish uniqueness. What I mean is that if $g$ is any other such matrix function, you can argue that the maps in each entry do the same thing that $f$'s entries do, and *their* uniqueness forces $f=g$. You can formalize the argument with entry projection maps from $M_2(E(M))\to E(M)$.

Comment: @rschwieb: Finally, I still have a question. If $f$ has that form, how do you prove that $f$ is an algebra homomorphism. It seems that this form doesn't make $f$ be an algebra homomorphism.

Comment: You get that *for free* from the universal property of $E(M)$ :) The first time the matrix is shown in the proof, it is describing a module homomorphism $f:M\to M_2(E(M))$ satisfying $f(x)^2=0$. Since $A=M_2(E(M))$ is an associative algebra, the universal property of $E(M)$ promotes $f:M\to A$ into an *algebra homomorphism* $f:E(M)\to A$.

Comment: @ rschwieb: Thank you at advance. And I don't know whether I twist the universal property. I have add some words to the question and to show more details about my question. Would you please have a look at the "editted" part?

Comment: @Andylang Great, I think it's a great question, and you are not far from seeing the answer. You have to remember that the second $D$ denotes the extension of the first $D$ (by abuse of notation) and that our whole purpose here is to prove that for that extension, $D(ab)=D(a)b+\overline{a}D(b)$. Your computation, along with the universal property's assertion "it is an algebra homomorphism" combine to *prove* that the extension of $D$ satisfies the antiderivation rule.